# Software support for roman numerals and functions

Tags: software, analysis, roman-numerals

I have seen how someone used Musescore, lyrics and a special font to attach roman numerals to a score. I have also seen examples of roman numerals in Sibelius. I have no idea how that was done.

I would like to understand the current situation regarding software support for roman numerals and functions (such as T for tonic) in digital scores.

- Which software is available that allows you to add roman numerals/functions to a score?
- Is it always done with a workaround via lyrics and a special font (probably making any existing real lyrics useless),
  or does some software have dedicated data for numerals/functions?

Related question: [Does MusicXML support roman numerals and/or functions?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/62316/44419)

Comment: Might I suggest that you separate this into (at least) two questions: one on software support, the other on representing roman-numeral or functional notation in MusicXML.

Comment: I have done so.

Answer (score 4):

[LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/) also provides support for Roman numerals; one such example can be found at the [LilyPond Snippet Repository](http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Search?q=roman%20numerals). It is done, as you said, with a lyrics workaround. (There's also a more advanced version of this floating around somewhere, waiting to be added in the near future.)

[image]

These Roman numerals can be replaced with other text. Furthermore, LilyPond's `markup` capabilities allow one to add arrows, symbols, etc. So you could have your `T` and `D` functions, then you can have an arrow connecting the two, or intermediary Riemannianian `S/S` functions, etc.

It's a very powerful tool, but there is a learning curve.